# Does ollydbg work in windows 8.1?

Tags: ollydbg

I was trying to learn how to use ollydbg and havent been able to fully get it working on windows 8.1.When i run the program i get this error:

[image: [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/8xk8qlF.jpg[/IMG]]

I have tried hitting yes and no and also downloding the psapl.dll file and putting it in the folder and it never fixes it.

Then when i search all referenced text strings, the window that opens always says:
"Text strings referenced in ntdll:.text" Im never able to search up the things i want to search for.Is this a common problem with running it on windows 8.1? I havent found a solution to it yet.I have used version 1-2 of ollydbg too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you run OllyDbg as administrator. It can be that it can't delete the file because it's in the program files folder. Then click "Yes" next time.

2) "Search all referenced text strings" will always search in the current module and section which is displayed in the CPU window. So it appears you are currently somewhere inside `ntdll`'s `.text` section. In order to search for strings in a different module, e.g. your main module, click "View" -> "Executable modules", double-click the module you want to search in, and then try again.